# How to force Sudden-Death Overtime gang to appear?

Tags: fallout-3

I'm playing Fallout 3 and I've started the Nuka Cola Challenge quest and was told a gang of hockey fans would appear during this quest at Red Racer Factory.

I visited the factory before and after visiting the Nuka Cola factory, even found one of the members corpses inside it with a note talking about they wanting to find the Nuka Cola Clear formula.

So far I haven't been able to encounter these gang members, searched around and didn't find corpses of any kind too.

Am I missing something? Is it a bug?  I'm playing the GOTY edition on PS3.

Comment: Did you give the lady the Nuka Cola Quantums yet?

Comment: No, I haven't delivered the Nuka Cola Quantums, the quest is still unfinished.

Comment: Do you have the Nuka Cola Clear formula?

Comment: No idea where to find it, do I need it to encounter these guys?

Comment: Yes, see the answer I just posted for more details

Answer (score 2):

From the Fallout wiki:

> The gang spawns in front of the Red Racer factory only if you have obtained the Nuka-Cola Clear formula from the Nuka-Cola plant before finishing the The Nuka-Cola Challenge. Finishing the quest will cause the gang to not spawn.

Sounds like you still need the formula. The locations are also listed on the wiki, [here is a link to the page.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nuka-Cola_Clear_formula)